# provided URI scheme'http' is invalid; expected 'https'

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a RESTful Web Service hosted in IIS 6.0, I am able to Browse the Service in browser. When i am trying to access the same service via Client console App, it is giving me the following error:

```
"provided URI scheme'http' is invalid; expected 'https', Parameter name: Via"
```

My WebService web.config has this settings:

```
<system.serviceModel>  
<services>  
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="TestAPI">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="RESTFriendly" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ITestAPI" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>     
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RESTFriendly">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

My Client App has App.config from where i am getting the address :

```
<appSettings>
<add key="WEBSERVICE" value="URL"/>
```

in the  Main method :

```
WebChannelFactory<ITestAPI> cf = new WebChannelFactory<IAPI>(baseAddress);
            WebHttpBinding wb =cf.Endpoint.Binding as WebHttpBinding;
            wb.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
            wb.Security.Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
            cf.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "usermane";
            cf.Credentials.UserName.Password = "password";

            ITestAPI channel = cf.CreateChannel();
            string msg = channel.TestMethod();
```

When it tries to call TestMethod, it gives me this error.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You're setting the security to transport mode, which is HTTPS, with this line:

`wb.Security.Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport;`

Is the value of `baseAddress` an HTTP or HTTPS address?

Comment: That's the problem.  You're specifying that you want a secure transport, but HTTP is not a secure transport.

Comment: This setting might alternatively be present in web.config, in an element like this: <security mode="Transport"> ... </security>
In that case, just remove or comment the whole security section, to be able to use http instead of https.

Comment: I am facing the same issue

Comment: This was very helpful. I did something like this in my code, to allow the program to handle both HTTPS and HTTP, depending on my URL Settings value. I have a production server that's configured to handle HTTPS, and a test server to handle HTTP (inside the network):


if (Settings.Default.URL.Contains("https://"))

{
 binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;

}

else

{

 binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;

}