# Calling a https web service (C#)

Tags: c#, web-services, https

I implemented a web service which is available under some https url. The client (a console app) calls it, but the following error is thrown:

*The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.*

I searched that in the net, but I am not really sure how to solve it? Is this solved by adding some code to the web service?

Thanks :-)

Comment: are you using WCF client to call it?

Comment: possible duplicates : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435823/the-provided-uri-scheme-https-is-invalid-expected-http-parameter-name-via

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690784/provided-uri-schemehttp-is-invalid-expected-https

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `<security mode="Transport">` on the binding.  This means it uses https.  Change the `<endpoint address=...>` to agree, or change to a non-transport-security http binding.

Was this svcutil-generated (Add Web Referenc) config?  What does the server config look like?  It is surprising to generate 'inconsistent' config like this from the metadata.

Regards

**Karan Shah**

Comment: Your answer didn't make sense, since you had tags inline in your text, and those get treated as tags, by default. I've marked them up as code.