# C# SOAP WebService: HTTPS endpoint configuration

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, https

In a C# service i must add a Web Service reference for calling some metods.
The testing URL use an HTTPS protocol, so I'm try to edit my endpoint to call new address:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="fooSoap" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>   
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://x.x.x.x/WS_Foo/Foo.asmx"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="fooSoap"
        contract="WSFooReferences.fooSoap" name="fooSoap" />
    </client>       
</system.serviceModel>
```

And so, I'm trying to call my method in c#:

```
WSFooReferences.fooSoapClient fooWS = new WSFooReferences.fooSoapClient();
int iRetCode = fooWS.Ping("ID12345");
```

But I've this error:

***The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'***

How I can edit my endpoint configuration fot this case?

T'ks!

Comment: That's strange as you didn't configure security as TransportMode: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1690956/3419300

Comment: Of cource.. I've missed to specify TransportMode, via config or - as your suggestion - via code. For example:

<system.serviceModel>
 <bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="fooSoap">
   **<security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />           
   </security>**
  </binding>
   </basicHttpBinding>
 </bindings>   
 <client>
   <endpoint address="http://x.x.x.x/WS_Foo/Foo.asmx"
  binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="fooSoap"
  contract="WSFooReferences.fooSoap" name="fooSoap" />
 </client>     
</system.serviceModel>

Comment: So, just to understand, are you getting the error WITH the security = TransportMode or WITHOUT it?

Comment: Really strange, usually you get that error when you have <security mode="Transport"> and you don't use https. I don't know how to help you, you have to investigate more.

Comment: Of course it is `securityMode = Transport`...